# How can I make CountDownTimer persist for a long time in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to create a CountDowntimer that the user can set and once it reaches zero a sound will play. However, I have an issue with long timers where the sound does play, not when the timer reaches zero, but when I unlock the phone. Also in this case the app state resets to the main activity. Using a foreground service I can get the timer to work up to 30 minutes or so. Without a foreground service, the maximum time was under ten minutes. What do I need to use to be able to keep the timer working?

Here are the most relevant pieces of code:

```kotlin
// TimerActivity class  
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    
        binding = ActivityTimerBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    
        textViewTimer = binding.textViewTimer
        buttonPause = binding.buttonPause
        buttonStop = binding.buttonStop
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.timersound)
        mediaPlayer.isLooping = false
    
        buttonPause.setOnClickListener {
            if (!isTimerPaused)
            {
                // Pause the countdown timer
                countdownTimer.cancel()
                isTimerPaused = true
                buttonPause.text = getString(R.string.resume)
    
                Intent(applicationContext, TimerService::class.java).also {
                    it.action = TimerService.PAUSE
                    startService(it)
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // Resume the countdown timer
                startCountdownTimer(timeRemainingMillis)
                isTimerPaused = false
                buttonPause.text = getString(R.string.pause)
            }
        }
    
        buttonStop.setOnClickListener {
            finishAndReturnActivity(timeRemainingMillis)
        }
    
        val timerMinutes = intent.getLongExtra("timerMinutes", 1)
        startCountdownTimer(timerMinutes * 60 * 1000)
    }
    
    private fun createCountDownTimer(millis: Long): CountDownTimer {
        // Create and return a new CountDownTimer
        return object : CountDownTimer(millis, 1000) {
            override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long)
            {
                // Update the countdown display on each tick
                timeRemainingMillis = millisUntilFinished
                val minutes = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) / 60
                val seconds = (millisUntilFinished / 1000) % 60
                val formattedTime = String.format("%02d:%02d", minutes, seconds)
                textViewTimer.text = formattedTime
            }
    
            override fun onFinish()
            {
                textViewTimer.text = "00:00"
                playBellSound()
                val timeLeft: Long = 0
                finishAndReturnActivity(timeLeft)
            }
        }
    }

private fun startCountdownTimer(millis: Long)
    {
        Intent(applicationContext, TimerService::class.java).also {
            it.action = TimerService.START
            startService(it)
        }
        // Initialize the countdown timer with an initial time of timerMinutes minutes
        countdownTimer = createCountDownTimer(millis)
        countdownTimer.start()
    }

// TimerService class

override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int
{
    when (intent?.action)
    {
        START -> start()
        PAUSE -> stopSelf()
    }

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId)
}

private fun start()
{
    val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
        .setContentTitle("Timer is running")
        .setContentText("Your timer is active.")
        .build()
    startForeground(1, notification)
}
```

Comment: You said answer yourself in your question. You should use foreground service to keep working countdown timer. Otherwise Android will kill your activity when on low memory or thinks that activity is no longer required.

Comment: @TayfunYILDIRIM he should **NOT** use a foreground service for **long-running** tasks that could NOT be in foreground, like a countdown timer.

Answer (score 0):

From the official [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background#recommended-approaches) about background work.

For Long-Running tasks you should opt for `WorkManager`.

From [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent) documentation:

> Work is persistent when it remains scheduled through app restarts and system reboots. WorkManager is the recommended solution for persistent work. Because most background processing is best accomplished through persistent work, WorkManager is therefore also the primary recommended API for background processing in general.

When to use `WorkManager` ?

> Long Running: Tasks which might run for longer, **potentially longer than 10 minutes.**

You can find the [getting started](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/persistent/getting-started) here about `WorkManager`.